# Replacing my light/fan/heater/timer with a light/fan/nightlight in the bathroom, with another light just to make things interesting

Tags: electrical

I have a 3-gang box which I will label A, B, and C, and Timer that I will label D.

A operates a light over the sink.

B operates the light on another fixture that includes a light, fan, and heater.

C operates the fan.

D operates the heater.

I am replacing the light/fan/heater unit with a light/fan/nightlight. I have no use for the timer. Since A controls an entirely different fixture, I am only concerned with B, C, and D for the new fixture.

[This is the link](http://www.pixball.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/wire-a-bathroom-light-with-a-exhaust-fan-bathroom-furniture-hunter-bathroom-fan-replacement-parts-hunter-bathroom-fans-with-light-1024x641.jpg) provided in the instructions, however the instructions speak to a multi-function switch. There's probably a couple of different ways to do this, but what I would prefer is that B remains controlling the Light, C remains for the fan, and D gets dedicated to the Night light.  I am not married to this set-up, but thought keep the switches arranged in deference to habit seems best.

Update: forgot to mention (duh!) that I have four (4) cables running into the 3-Gang.  As I said, I am open to suggestions, so if you think it is best to purchase a multi-function switch, I can run out and get one, and I am not opposed to throwing in a GFCI as one of the 3-Gang.  I am attaching a [couple of images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6sfNdtoREigaTVwSDVJbDd0Q3c), but my apologies, as there is poor lighting with the breakers off.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: Is the timer in a different box?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel just posted a couple of pics, but they are difficult to decipher. From Right to Left, the switches are A, B, and C. Thank you for pondering my situation.

Comment: @mmathis the Time is NOT in the the 3-Gang. It sits all by itself for the moment.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box for the light/fan/heater fixture?  Can you also post the instructions (or at least make/model) for the light/fan/nightlight?

Answer (score 1):

Gang together all the white wires loop the hot wire to bottom of all switches and you should be left with three wires to attach to the tops of each switch

Comment: Thanks @doug savery that is what I eventually ended up with, plus I removed the Timer and I added in a dedicated nightlight that goes on at dusk and of at dawn. I am pleased with the outcome. I really appreciate everyone's willingness to assist.